# Editing prompt in javascript

Tags: javascript

In my web application, I have a page with several input values, and would like to confirm that the user wants to leave the page if the user tries to leave with unsaved information entered (similar to the prompts on exiting Microsoft Word with unsaved changes on the document). I would like to display a custom message along the lines of "You have made changes which have not been saved. Do you really wish to leave the page?" How can I go about doing this?

Comment: ok soory sir for this:but please give the solution for the editing prompt

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use the `change` event on all your inputs to detect any changes made by the user. This event doesn't bubble, so you'll need to attach it to each input individually. Then you'll need to use the `beforeunload` event of the `window` object to prompt the user.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var anythingEdited = false;

    function inputChanged() {
        anythingEdited = true;
    }

    window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) {
        if (anythingEdited) {
            evt = evt || window.event;
            evt.returnValue = "You have edited something. If you click OK, your changes will be lost.";
        }
    };
</script>

First name: <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" onchange="inputChanged();">
```

Comment: it can not work sir. Defalut message of the onbefore load also comes.i want to show my own custom message.But it also show the dafault message

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to achieve what you want. You can add your own message as shown above but you cannot prevent the default message appearing too.

Comment: Tim Down is correct, browsers added this default message because spammers used to word the custom message to trick users into staying on the site.